# Why is the derivative of $y=\frac x y$ different from the derivative of $y^2=x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

<sub>I am trying to teach myself calculus but I can't overcome this question...</sub>

---

Since, graphically, equations $y = \frac x y$ and $y^2=x$ are the same, how come $\frac {dy}{dx}$ of the former is $\frac{y}{y^2+x}$ while the derivative of the latter is $\frac{1}{2y}$? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Equations do not have "derivatives". **Functions** have derivatives.

In your case, from the question, it is unclear whether $x$ is a function of $y$ or if $y$ is a function of $x$. It is also not clear which variable you are deriving by.

Comment: @5xum Thanks for the note! I meant $dy/dx$; I've added it on the main question!

Comment: Let $y'=\dfrac {y}{(y^2+x)}=\dfrac {1}{(y + \dfrac x y)}$. But $\dfrac x y = y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh, so they do be the same... I didn't realise that, thank you for the answer!

Comment: There are a lot of equations that are satisified by x,y and y', if y=sqrt(x)

Comment: They do be the same? Did I somehow misclick and found myself on Reddit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Equations do not have "derivatives". **Functions** have derivatives.

If you "take a derivative" of an equation, what you are really doing is taking the derivative of *both sides* of the equation, meaning the result **must also be an equation**.

So when you say that the derivative of $y=\frac xy$ is $\frac{y}{y^2+x}$, that sentence makes no sense.

What you **can** say is that if you take the derivative of **both** sides of the equation, you then get

$$\frac{d}{dx} y = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{y}.$$

You can then simplify this expression, using the rule of differentiating fractions, to get

$$y' = \frac{y - y'\cdot x}{y^2}$$

and from here, you can get that

$$y' = \frac{y}{y^2+x}.$$

---

On the other hand, you can similarly manipulate the expression $y^2=x$ to get that $$y' = \frac{1}{2y}$$

and these two expressions are in no way contradictiory. In fact, both relations are true, and you can actually morph one into the other since

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2y} &=\frac{1}{y+y}
\\&=\frac{1}{y + \frac{x}{y}}
\\&=\frac{1}{\frac{y^2+x}{y}}
\\&=\frac{y}{y^2+x}\end{align}$$

where I used the fact that $y=\frac xy$ to get from the first row to the second.

Comment: But can't we say that $x=y^2$ is equivalent to either of the functions $y=\pm \sqrt x$. Hence $y'=\frac 1{\pm2\sqrt x}=\frac 1y$ ?

Comment: @MasterShifu How did you get $$\frac{1}{\pm2\sqrt x}=\frac1y?$$ Did you mean $\frac1{2y}$? If so, then sure, you can say that.

Comment: Yes I missed $2$ in the denominator. thanks!

Comment: @MasterShifu In that case, yes, you can use your way to get to the relation. But it's actually even easier to me to just take $y^2=x$ and take the derivative of both sides of the equation to get $2yy' = 1$ and then $y'=\frac{1}{2y}$. There is no messy handling of plus or minus.

Answer (score 2):

That's a perfectly reasonable question. I like to write implicit derivatives like this one in terms of the differential and variations in the independent variable, with $\delta y = dy\,\delta x$ denoting the first-order change in $y(x)$ due to the variation $\delta x$ in $x$.

If we differentiate both sides of both equations we get
$$dy\,\delta x = \frac{1}{y(x)} \delta x - \frac{x}{y(x)^2} \, dy\,\delta x$$
and
$$2y(x) dy\,\delta x = \delta x.$$
**Note** that this procedure is only well-defined when the conditions of the implicit function theorem hold, i.e., away from $x=0$.

Solving for $\delta y$ in both cases,
$$\left(1 + \frac{x}{y(x)^2}\right)\delta y = \frac{1}{y(x)} \delta x$$
$$\delta y = \frac{1}{2 y(x)}\delta x.$$
Plugging in $y = \sqrt{x}$ (or $y = -\sqrt{x}$, depending on which branch you're on) you will see that both expressions are equal.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! I see now! The only thing is that I don't understand why you use $dyδx$ instead of $dy/dx$. Are they the same?